# Looking for an alternative method to this query

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are 2 tables, a Component table and a Log table. The component table holds the actual(current) value description and a timestamp when it was last updated.

The Log table contains a component ID that references to wich component it belongs:

```
Component:
Id 
Actual
LastUpdated

Log: 
Id
ComponentId
Value
Timestamp
```

the query that used to work but currently lock the table looks like this.

```
update Component set Actual = 
(select top 1 Value from Log
where Component.Id = ComponentId
order by Id desc), 
LastUpdated = 
(select top 1 TimeStamp from Log
where Component.Id = ComponentId
order by Id desc)
```

Both the log and component tables are growing and this query can't keep up like it used to be able to do. there are around 80 components now and a couple of million records.

Is it possible to work in a way like this and just improve the query or is the entire approach wrong?

ps the devices that send the data don't have an reliable system time and therefor having them update the component table leads to inconsistency. When inserting a log i take the system time on the SQL server(default value)

EDIT:

taking a suggestion from the awnsers im trying to create a trigger on log to automaticly update Component when a log is created.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_log_ins
ON Log
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
   update Component
   SET Actual = (SELECT i.value FROM inserted as i),
   LastUpdated = (SELECT i.Timestamp FROM inserted as i);
END;
```

but for some reason the query doesn't finish and keeps executing.

Comment: What dbms are you using? I assume sql-server?

Comment: yes sql server @Yossi

Comment: Can you show sample data and output?

Comment: Could `Actual` and `TimeStamp` on `Component`  be computed columns that do the lookup? It may or may not be better but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going about this all wrong. A better solution would be a trigger on the Component table, that inserts into the Log table whenever a Component is inserted or updated.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_component_biu 
ON Component
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO Log(
      ComponentId,
      Value,
      Timestamp
   )
   SELECT
      Id,
      Actual,
      LastUpdated
   FROM inserted;
END;
```

Comment: yes i love the idea, but it should be the otherway around. When a log gets inserted i need to update the component table

Comment: @MickBoe1 Why? The effect is the same. Also, your Component table should probably be a view; see [my other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35767745/2936460).

Comment: So when i try to execute, 

CREATE TRIGGER trg_component_biu 
ON Log
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
   update Component
   SET Actual = (SELECT i.value FROM inserted as i),
   LastUpdated = (SELECT i.Timestamp FROM inserted as i);
END;    it just keeps executing and lock the component table... i think it can be the same problem as why the query is hanging (or taking really long)

Comment: That's because you're not telling it _WHERE_ to update, so it's updating all records. Did you have a backup?

Comment: No but its not an issue because actual and lastupdated are changed constantly. the log is the important table

Comment: edit: adding the where clause, still keeps the the create trigger qeury to hang

Comment: @MickBoe1, `create trigger` query hangs - sounds like the `log` table on which you are creating the trigger is in use/locked and your `create trigger` statement waits for the locking transaction to finish. The code of your trigger is not correct, but it is a different story.

Comment: there seem to be a missing where in the trigger thats correct. but i can't seem to find what is using the log table :/

Answer (score 0):

Based on `TOP 1` in your query I guess you are using `SQL SERVER`. In SQL Server you can use `OUTER APPLY`

```
UPDATE c
SET    c.Actual = cs.Value,
       c.LastUpdated = cs.TimeStamp
FROM   Component C
       OUTER apply (SELECT TOP 1 TimeStamp,
                                 ComponentId
                    FROM   Log l
                    WHERE  c.Id = l.ComponentId
                    ORDER  BY Id DESC) cs
```

Adding a `non-clustered index` on `Log` table `ID` column and include `TimeStamp,ComponentId` will improve query performance

Another way is using `ROW_NUMBER` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

```
UPDATE c
SET    c.Actual = cs.Value,
       c.LastUpdated = cs.TimeStamp
FROM   Component C
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY ComponentId 
                                   ORDER BY id DESC) rn,*
                        FROM   Log) cs
                    ON cs.ComponentId = c.id
                       AND cs.rn = 1
```

Comment: @Yossi - Because the original query updates the non matching records with `NULL` value

Comment: I don't think its possible for non match.. I assume he store every insert to log table,so there will always be a record

Comment: Also, both of your queries wont work.. HINT: look at the join condition

Comment: @Yossi - You should never assume.

Comment: Ok, I agree.. left join can't harm even if I'm right so I'll change my answer

Comment: @Yossi  - If you change it is going to be duplicate of my answer ;p

Comment: :S:S:S Actualy I believe I posted mine before you add the row_number solution.. But fine, I'll leave it an inner join

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using ROW_NUMBER() like this:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.Actual = t2.value,
    t1.LastUpdated = t2.TimeStamp
FROM Component t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT log.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY log.componentID order by log.ID DESC) as rnk
            FROM log) t2
ON(t2.componentID = t1.id and t2.rnk = 1)
```

Comment: This is not same as original query

Comment: Yes it is, as mentioned in your answer comments, I doubt non match is possible

Comment: I canceled the query when it reached 30 seconds. perhaps something else is wrong...

Comment: @MickBoe1 Try adding an index on both tables

Answer (score 0):

All data in your Component table is coming from the Log table. Instead of making Component an actual table, you can make it a view, indexed if necessary.

```
CREATE VIEW Component
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   SELECT
      ComponentId AS Id,
      FIRST_VALUE(Value)
         OVER(PARTITION BY ComponentId
              ORDER BY Timestamp DESC)
         AS Actual,
      MAX(Timestamp) AS LastUpdated
   FROM Log
   GROUP BY ComponentId;
```

Comment: Component actually holds more data but it was kinda inrelavent to this problem so i left it out...

Comment: Then your database appears to be not normalised properly.

Comment: things like max min and setpoint values are very relevant to every component. but do not matter to this problem. Anyway there seems to be that something else is the problem but i've got no idea whats going on

Comment: In that case, you should have a separate Component table, a ComponentLog table, and a ComponentCurrent view that joins those two.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use trigger on the `Log` table it has to work even if several rows are inserted. Here is one possible variant.

Also, this variant would not capture values for a new `ComponentID` that doesn't exist in the `Component` table yet.

If there is a possibility that such values would be inserted into the `Log` table, I'd use `MERGE` instead of simple `UPDATE`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_log_ins
ON Log
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    WITH
    CTE
    AS
    (
        SELECT
            Component.Actual AS OldValue
            ,Component.LastUpdated AS OldTimestamp
            ,inserted.Value AS NewValue
            ,inserted.Timestamp AS NewTimestamp
        FROM
            Component
            INNER JOIN inserted ON inserted.ComponentID = Component.ID
    )
    UPDATE CTE
    SET
        OldValue = NewValue,
        OldTimestamp = NewTimestamp
    ;
END
```

Also, if it is possible to insert into `Log` several rows with the same `ComponentID` in the same `INSERT` statement, you'd better choose explicitly which value to use for update. Likely, the one with the latest `Timestamp`.

So, the query becomes more complicated:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_log_ins
ON Log
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    WITH
    CTE_InsertedRowNumbers
    AS
    (
        SELECT
            inserted.ComponentID
            ,inserted.Value AS NewValue
            ,inserted.Timestamp AS NewTimestamp
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY inserted.ComponentID 
                ORDER BY inserted.Timestamp DESC, inserted.ID DESC) AS rn
        FROM inserted
    )
    ,CTE_LatestInsertedComponents
    AS
    (
        SELECT
            ComponentID
            ,NewValue
            ,NewTimestamp
        FROM CTE_InsertedRowNumbers
        WHERE rn = 1
    )
    ,CTE
    AS
    (
        SELECT
            Component.Actual AS OldValue
            ,Component.LastUpdated AS OldTimestamp
            ,CTE_LatestInsertedComponents.NewValue
            ,CTE_LatestInsertedComponents.NewTimestamp
        FROM
            Component
            INNER JOIN CTE_LatestInsertedComponents 
                ON CTE_LatestInsertedComponents.ComponentID = Component.ID
    )
    UPDATE CTE
    SET
        OldValue = NewValue,
        OldTimestamp = NewTimestamp
    ;
END
```